# Typesetting "hollow slash"

Tags: symbols

How can I typeset the hollow forward and backward slashes (in mathmode) as used in the attached image? They need to be used alongside normal forward and backward slashes.

[image: Barker & Shan, Continuations and Natural Language. OUP.]

Comment: `stmaryrd` has `\fatslash` and `\fatbslash`, but I can never remember how it interacts with `amssymb`.

Comment: Have a google on: `latex double slash symbol`.

Comment: @campa If you change your comment to an answer I'll accept it. The spacing is a bit weird but that can be tweaked.

Comment: Uhm, that's true, especially for `\fatslash`. The glyph isn't at all centred in its box: there is a huge space on the left, and the glyph protrudes on the right. That's quite strange...

Comment: @campa `stmaryrd` plays well with `amssymb`.  Agreed, the bounding box is very strange.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I had the option `heavyvircles` in mind and for some reason I thought it had something to do with `amssymb`. Now I've looked at the doc again. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These symbols are defined by the `stmaryrd` package under the names `\fat(b)slash` (the spacing for \fatslash is not so good):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\[ A\fatbslash B\qquad C \fatslash D \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: as suggested by @AndrewSwann, we can have a much better spacing for `\fatslash` using this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\newcommand{\myfatslash}{\mathbin{\mkern-6mu\fatslash}}

\begin{document}

\[ A\fatbslash B\qquad C\myfatslash D \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 The spacing can be helped with `\newcommand{\myfatslash}{\mathbin{\mkern-6mu\fatslash}}`

Answer (score 10):

You can use `\holwd` to set the gap.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\hollowslash{\setbox0=\hbox{/}\def\holwd{3pt}%
  \stackengine{-.3pt}{/}{\rlap{\kern-1pt\rule{\holwd}{.4pt}}}{O}{r}{F}{F}{S}%
  \kern\dimexpr\holwd-\wd0-.2pt\relax%
  \stackengine{-.4pt}{/}{\llap{\rule{\holwd}{.4pt}\kern-1pt}}{U}{l}{F}{F}{S}%
}
\newcommand\hollowbackslash{\setbox0=\hbox{\textbackslash}\def\holwd{2.8pt}%
  \stackengine{-.4pt}{\textbackslash}{\rlap{\kern-1pt\rule{\holwd}{.4pt}}}{U}{r}{F}{F}{S}%
  \kern\dimexpr\holwd-\wd0-.2pt\relax%
  \stackengine{-.3pt}{\textbackslash}{\llap{\rule{\holwd}{.4pt}\kern-1pt}}{O}{l}{F}{F}{S}%
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$C\hollowslash(A\hollowbackslash B)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't mind loading the `graphicx` package, you can use `\reflectbox` to cut down on the code.  Here it is with `\holwd` set to `2pt`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\hollowslash{\setbox0=\hbox{/}\def\holwd{2pt}%
  \stackengine{-.3pt}{/}{\rlap{\kern-1pt\rule{\holwd}{.4pt}}}{O}{r}{F}{F}{S}%
  \kern\dimexpr\holwd-\wd0-.2pt\relax%
  \stackengine{-.4pt}{/}{\llap{\rule{\holwd}{.4pt}\kern-1pt}}{U}{l}{F}{F}{S}%
}
\newcommand\hollowbackslash{\reflectbox{\hollowslash}}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\begin{document}
$C\hollowslash(A\hollowbackslash B)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great and fantastic!

Comment: Interesting, but I don't understand why your `\dimexpr` works. Isn't a `\relax` at the end a required part of the syntax?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I should add it, but I don't believe it is mandatory unless I start nesting things.  The reason it is best practice is to cover those situations when you don't know in advance what will follow.  If what follows just happened to be `+3pt`, that would get sucked into the `\dimexpr` unexpectedly.  I knew that `\stackengine`, which actually follows the dimensional calculation, would not be confused for a dimensional operation.

Comment: OK. I just looked it up, and it says `\dimexpr`⟨dimen expr⟩⟨optional spaces and `\relax`⟩, which makes it clear that the `\relax` is also optional. I have clearly been too hasty reading the docs.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen It is certainly a best practice, and I will make an edit.